# set multidimensional array batch

Tags: arrays, windows, batch-file, multidimensional-array

I am creating multidimensional arrays these way:

```
set Name[0]="name1"
set Id[0]=1234
set Action[0]=false

set Name[1]="name2"
set Id[1]=5678
set Action[1]=true
```

Then loop:

```
set "x=0"

:SymLoop
if defined Id[%x%] (
if defined Action[%x%] (
if defined Name[%x%] (

call set "name=%%Name[%x%]%%"
call set "id=%%Id[%x%]%%"
call set "action=%%Action[%x%]%%"

:: use name, id, action

)
set /a "x+=1"
GOTO :SymLoop
)
)
)
```

Is there some different approach to create multidimensional array without setting each key manually? When I define array and change order (key number), then I need to re-arange whole array to have right "key values".

Is there something like

```
set myArray ["name1", 1234, false]
set myArray ["name2", 5678, true]
```

and then iterate in loop and define 
- "name1" as "name" variable
- 1234 set as "id" variable
- "false" as "action" variable

in loop? Reducing use of "_x" variable definition

Note: I am novice at windows batch

Comment: Do you actually have to define each array in the script or do you want to generate random arrays? if you have a list of arrays, then store them in a file and read it.

Comment: Good idea. I define array manually, but its annoing for me, trying to automate process.

Comment: ok, will post answer quick.

Comment: Do you actually want to generate the array and print it to file? or do you have an array and want to read from it?

Comment: I have an array (define it on start) and iterate thru it.

Comment: Something like in my answer?

Comment: Similair. Can I define it inside `my.bat` on start somehow ?

Comment: Yes we can. Just need to change layout and delims. I will look at it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So simply add your array in a file:

```
Name1,1234,false
Name2,4567,true
```

then your batch:

```
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%i in (newfile.txt) do (
 echo name=%%i
 echo id=%%j
 echo action=%%k
)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM build a 2d-array:
for %%i in (Name,Id,Action) do (
  for /l %%j in (0,1,5) do (
    set array[%%i,%%j]=!random!
  )
)
set array
REM show a certain element:
echo third Name = %array[Name,3]%
```

or to keep close to your example:

```
set array[Name,0]="John"
set array[Id,0]=1234
set array[Action,0]=false

set array[Name,1]="Jane"
set array[Id,1]=9876
set array[Action,1]=true

set array
echo second Name = %array[Name,1]%
```

Comment: I try to avoid key (e.g. [Name,0] that 0 is key), so when I move some row, I don't need to reorder all keys

Comment: the problem is: there is no thing like an array in `cmd`. It's just a bunch of independent variables. And you will need something like an index or key to address a certain entry (variable here)

Answer (score -1):

For with /f can parse your "json" array (treats consecutive delimiters as one and empty fields as nonexistent, space in delims is important)

```
@echo off
set myArray=["name1", 1234, false]

for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=,[] " %%i in ("%myArray%") DO (
  echo name=%%i
  echo id=id=%%j
  echo action=%%k
)
```

Comment: if I define more `set myArray=["name2", 5678, true]`, how do I iterate thru that ? Will I have myArray 2 entries ?

Comment: You can't have more than one variable with the same name. You overwrite it every time, you use `set myArray=...`